# set up transport modes osrm

Tags: json, open-source-routing-machine

I wondered if anyone could help. I have setup osrm on a spare computer it is running on Ubuntu 14. It works fine and I can query it using the default car setting for transport. I would like to be able to setup and use different modes of transport ie foot and public transport as well. the query I send to osrm is this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://192.168.0.4:5000/viaroute?loc=$startlat,$startlong&loc=$endlat,$endlong&instructions=false&alt=false&geometry=false");
```

Answer (score 1):

OSRM does not provide currently a public transportation feature. However, you can set different profiles as by foot or by bicycle by changing the routing profile.

OSRM's routing profiles are located in the folder profiles of the Project-OSRM directory. You will find already there three profiles: bicycle.lua, car.lua and foot.lua. These profiles are written in Lua, an embedded scripting language.

If you only want to use these profiles, without modifying them, simply specify it in your calls to osrm-extract and osrm-prepare. 
Way better explanation [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Profiles).